# New Wordpress site without cpanel access

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

A client asked me to provide them a translation of their established wordpress site. None of the available plugins would be able to translate the site accurately as there is way too much customization on the theme and neither plugin would pick all the strings and the inputs would be mostly done by hand.

For that reason I was considering a network multisite where each site would be a new translation on a subdomain for each one, but that would require wildcarding the dns on cpanel level. 
(https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Domain-based)

The other option I came up with was installing a new wordpress on a subdirectory on the same domain, using a different prefix for the tables of the new wordpress in the same MySQL table (as a new table would require cpanel access), the drawback there would be the need to clean urls and redirects in the new site as it would be built up from the original page backup. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Is there any alternative I am missing, or am I looking at it from a totally erroneous point of view?

Thanks in advance, Jordi

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds a *lot* more complicated than just tweaking the existing theme to be fully translatable. It'll take a few hours of finding untranslated strings one-by-one, but you'll be avoiding a giant maintenance headache.

Comment: You can try WMPL plugin to translate website, they have had facility to translate all the strings in website